# Firefox add-on : passing value from context menu to contentScriptFile after selection

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing an addon, when user selects a value and right click on context menu .. properties of that object must be stored.

Below is my code

### **Main.js**

```
var contextMenu = require("sdk/context-menu");

var menuItem = contextMenu.Item({
  label: "Log Selection",
  context: contextMenu.SelectionContext(),
  contentScript: 'self.on("click", function () {' +
                 '  var text = window.getSelection().toString();' +
                 '  self.postMessage(text);' +
                 '});',
  accessKey: "l",
  onMessage: function (selectionText) {
    console.log(selectionText);
    contentScriptFile: [data.url("test.js")]

    }
});
```

---

below is the test.js where i wanted to take selectiontext object and print its innerhtml

test.js

```
parseElement(document.getElementById("selectionText"));

function parseElement(Element)
{
  if (Element == null)
    return;
alert(Element.innerHTML);
```

below are some issues which i am facing, please kindly help me

1. i am not able to understand how to get properties of selection text like inspect element
2. how can i pass selected text properties to main.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function in your `data.js` is called `parseElement`.  But a selection can contain part of an element, or many elements, each of which can have its own HTML tag and CSS properties.  It's actually quite complicated.

In a content script, `document.getSelection()` will return a `Selection` object.  This `Selection` contains a number of `Range`s given by `document.getSelection().rangeCount`.  The first range (there won't be more than one unless you have selected multiple ranges using the ctrl-key) is given by `document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)`.  For the rest of this answer I'll assume only one range in the `Selection`, which should cover the vast majority of use cases.  The following expression represents the single-range selection:

```
var selection = document.getSelection();
var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
```

Unfortunately, there's no quick and dirty way (that I know of) to get a list of all the HTML elements associated with the range.  The `Range` class does have a property that gives the common ancestor, which is the smallest `Node` that contains all the elements which are wholly or partially contained by the `Range`:

```
var ancestorContainer = range.commonAncestorContainer;
```

All HTML elements are represented by `Node`s, by the way.  Not all `Node`s are elements.  For those that are, the `.nodeType` property has the value `Node.ELEMENT_NODE`. There are at most two nodes that are partially inside the `Range`.  These are `range.startContainer` and `range.endContainer`.  As for the nodes that are (1) entirely within the selection and (2) are elements, a [`NodeIterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator) is probably the most straightforward way to get a definitive list of them:

```
var nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(
  // first argument is the root node at which to begin the NodeIterator's traversal:
 ancestorContainer,
 // second argument 'whatToShow'; we're interested in elements:
 NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
 // third argument 'filter', a function whose return value tells iterator which nodes to iterate over.
 function (node) {
  return selection.containsNode(node) ? NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT : NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
 }
);
```

Then there is the business of getting actual `Node`s (which in this case are `Element`s) from the `NodeIterator`:

```
var elementsWithinSelection = [];
var e = nodeIterator.nextNode();
while (e) {
 elementsWithinSelection.push(e);
 e = nodeIterator.nextNode();
}
```

As for the properties of each [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), their `.tagName`, `.textContent` and `.style` properties should contain the information you need.  Sending information to the function that you wrote to be the property of `onMessage` is a matter of using `self.postMessage(string)`.  One example (that sort of fits what you're describing) might be:

```
self.postMessage(JSON.stringify(elementsWithinSelection.map(function (e) {
 return e.outerHTML;
})));
```